# Read input value and add class via javascript

Tags: jquery, html, input, addclass

I am new to jQuery and hope someone can show me an example of how to check an input value and add a class:

For example:

```
if($('#myFieldId').val() == 1) {
    $('#myFieldId').addClass('info');
} else if($('#myFieldId').val() == 0) {
    $('#myFieldId').addClass('muted');
}
```

I have a simple messaging system so when a user has viewed a message it changes the value to 1.

So I want to add a class to a table row if the value is = 0 to indicate an unread/new message

Comment: Google Search is your best friend. [Events | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/events/), [addClass | jQuery API Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/). At the least you should show us your HTML and the jQuery code you've written so far ..

Comment: You should really consider putting more effort in looking this up - the web is flooded with answers to this question.  Try to find an answer yourself and it will help you enormously in the long run. When you're stuck, people here will be more than glad to help you.

Comment: You're not attaching this code to any event by the looks of it, so while your general concept of how to check the value makes sense, you're not utilizing this code in the proper way. If you're not skilled with jQuery, are you skilled with javascript? If not, then perhaps you should start a tutorial, if you are, then you should know that you will need to bind an event to the DOM element that should be firing off this check

Answer (score 0):

Use the `val()` function to get an input fields current value, and the `addClass()` function to add a class to the specified field.

Just substitute the **#myFieldId** with the *jQuery selector* you are using for your input field:

```
if($('#myFieldId').val() == 1) {
    $('#myFieldId').addClass('info');
} else if($('#myFieldId').val() == 0) {
    $('#myFieldId').addClass('muted');
}
```

Comment: This is adding just the class info to all elements

Comment: It will add the class to all the elements that match the jQuery selector you are using, so if the selector used matches multiple elements, it will be added to all of them. If you only need to add the class to one specific field, try using the id property of that field as the jQuery selector. If you posted your jQuery code you are using it would be easier to help you.

Comment: if($('.read-unread').val() == 0) {
    $('td.preview').addClass('info');
};

Comment: You need to post the entire example in your question. (HTML & jQuery example.) You are not providing enough info to be able to accurately answer your question.